# How to handle Excel menu change / click event in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

[image]I have created Office 2010 Excel AddIn using AddIn Express product. I am using AddIn Express to support different version of Excel. During add-in load, I am authenticating user, which takes around 1-2 seconds for intranet users and external users are authenticated using form based authentication. Once authenticated, add-in gets loaded successfully and it shows application name in Excel menu.

I want to know if it is at all possible to authenticate user when s/he clicks on application menu name under Excel menu, as it might be the case that user want to use Excel only and not the Add-in. As of now, since I am authenticating user each time s/he starts Excel, it adds a delay in starting Excel. I am not able to identify proper event / method which I can handle when user clicks on application menu name.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: define `Application menu name`? Which part of the UI are you talking about? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Application menu name refers my add-in name [Macdata2], which gets integrated with excel menu when I start the application. I have attached a screenshot now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Avoid delay during the start up**

You could try delay loading Addin. You need to set the Load Behavior for the addin in the registry to 8 or 9.

Only when the ribbon tab is clicked the addins will be loaded but again there will be same delay in showing up the ribbon tab for the first time.

More about delay loading addins are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/04/19/delay-loading-the-clr-in-office-add-ins.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for response Kiru, I will give it a try. But I think, delay in showing up the ribbon tab for the first time wont be acceptable to business.

Comment: To be clear the tab will be shown when you start the Excel, but the Addin_Startup events and Ribbon_Load will be fired only when the ribbon tab is activated for first time. This is a simple change so you could try this and see

Comment: After further discussion within my team and business ppl, I have changed the implementation of authenticating user during add-in load. Now I am authenticating user whenever he makes first call to the backend service. Your solution would probably work fine in VSTO based add-in. I am using Add-in express which has its wrapper APIs and I was not able to find how to delay load 'Add-in Express' based Excel add-in. I appreciate your help though. Thanks.